# Tikz: how to create a new shape type: comment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a flowchart diagram with a comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.7cm, auto]
\tikzset{
        line/.style = {draw},
        comment/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em,fill=white},
        terminator/.style = {shape=rounded rectangle, draw, inner sep=2mm},
}

\node[terminator] (node-1) {begin};

\node [comment, below of=node-1] (node-2) {comment comment comment};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \draw[fill=gray!40] ($(node-2.south west)+(-2mm,-2mm)$) rectangle ($(node-2.north east)+(2mm, 2mm)$);
\end{scope}

\path [line] (node-1) -- ($(node-2.north)+(0mm,+2mm)$);

\node[terminator, below of=node-2, node distance=1.5cm] (node-3) {end};

\path [line] ($(node-2.south)+(0mm,-2mm)$) -- (node-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives this:

[image]

But comment is not a block, but 2 elements: background layer and a rounded rectangle. How to make new shape from it with anchors?

Comment: Search for `\pgfdeclareshape` in the PGF/Tikz manual. You could also read the code for simple geometric shapes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's tricky but it could work. You can draw the `background node` and place a `label node` over it with `center` option.

Problems: you have to adjust main node size repeating same text and fixing `inner sep`.
Advantatge: you can use `main node` anchors to draw edges.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.7cm, auto]
\tikzset{
        line/.style = {draw},
        comment/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, 
                rounded corners, minimum height=2em,fill=white},
        comment border/.style = {comment, rounded corners=0pt, 
                fill=gray!40, inner sep=4mm, minimum height=2em+4mm},
        terminator/.style = {shape=rounded rectangle, draw, inner sep=2mm},
}

\node[terminator] (node-1) {begin};

\node [comment border, below of=node-1,
       label={[comment]center:comment comment comment}] 
      (node-2) {comment comment comment};

\node[terminator, below of=node-2, node distance=1.5cm] (node-3) {end};

\draw (node-1)--(node-2);
\draw (node-2)--(node-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to use this trick, try with [`makeshape`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeshape) which today was announced in CTAN.

*EDIT: 2on Option*

Another not so tricky option would be to use a `matrix of nodes` node. A `matrix` is a `node` which contains other `nodes`, therefore it's possible to apply different styles to the matrix and every node.

```
comment/.style = {matrix of nodes, 
% Next lines apply to matrix and all inner nodes
                  draw, fill=gray!40, inner sep=5pt, 
% Next lines define style for inner nodes.
% It's possible to change previous options 
                  nodes={text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em, 
                          fill=white, inner sep=3pt}
                  },
```

All rows inside a `matrix` has to be finished with '\', then we need to be careful when
using `comment` nodes and include `\\` inside the `text` part:

```
\node [comment, below of=node-1] 
      (node-2) {comment comment comment\\};
```

The result will be the same, but the code changes to:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,matrix} %<- Don't forget matrix library
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.7cm, auto]
\tikzset{
        line/.style = {draw},
        comment/.style = {matrix of nodes, 
        % Next lines apply to matrix and all inner nodes
                           draw, fill=gray!40, inner sep=5pt, 
        % Next lines define style for inner nodes.
        % It's possible to change previous options 
                          nodes={text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em, 
                          fill=white, inner sep=3pt}
                          },            
        terminator/.style = {shape=rounded rectangle, draw, inner sep=2mm},
}

\node[terminator] (node-1) {begin};

\node [comment, below of=node-1] 
      (node-2) {comment comment comment\\};

\node[terminator, below of=node-2, node distance=1.5cm] (node-3) {end};

\draw (node-1)--(node-2);
\draw (node-2)--(node-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution via `append path picture`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
        line/.style = {draw},
        comment/.style = {
          draw, text centered,
          minimum height=2em+4mm, inner xsep=.3333em+4mm,
          append after command={\pgfextra{
              \pgfinterruptpath
              % fill white
              \fill[white] (\tikzlastnode.south west)
              rectangle (\tikzlastnode.north east);
              % fill gray region
              \fill[fill=gray,even odd rule,draw]
              (\tikzlastnode.south west) rectangle (\tikzlastnode.north east)
              [rounded corners]
              ([shift={(2mm,2mm)}]\tikzlastnode.south west)
              rectangle ([shift={(-2mm,-2mm)}]\tikzlastnode.north east);
              \endpgfinterruptpath
            }
          },
        },
        terminator/.style = {rounded corners, draw, inner sep=2mm},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid,node distance=1.7cm]
\node[terminator] (node-1) {begin};
\node [comment, below=1.7cm of node-1] (node-2) {comment comment comment};
\path [line] (node-1) -- (node-2);
\node[terminator, below=1.5cm of node-2] (node-3) {end};
\path [line] (node-2) -- (node-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```