# pgf/tikz: Making the filling / gap between double border lines transparent

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have a rectangular box with double border lines. The pgf manual (chapter 15.3.5 Graphic Parameters: Double Lines and Bordered Lines) says that the default filling is white. I want the gap to be transparent so that you can see the background color.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (myNode1) at (0,0) [
                          rectangle,
                          draw,
                          double,
                          double distance=1mm
                        ] {Double};
%                      
\node (myNode2) at (0,-1) [
                          rectangle,
                          draw,
                          double=transparent,
                          double distance=1mm
                        ] {Double};
%                 
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \coordinate (center) at (0, -.5);
    \fill [green!50!black!25] (center) rectangle ++(-1,1);
    \fill [orange!25] (center) rectangle ++(1,1);
    \fill [red!25] (center) rectangle ++(-1,-1);
    \fill [blue!25] (center) rectangle ++(1,-1);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output with wrong transparency]

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I do not want to give the gap manually the same color as the background since I want to be the background "anything" like a picture or something that is not of control of tikz.

Comment: Does `double=none` do what you want?

Comment: Hello Peter. Sadly it does not seem to help.

Comment: Instead of `double` lines you can use one of the answers to [tikz-how-to-create-a-new-shape-type-comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95952/1952)

Comment: A double line is drawn twice; one with outer color and on top of it thinner line with the inner color. So if you say the color of the thinner line should be transparent, the outer one is still shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is to give the same color to `double` as that of the background:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (myNode1) at (0,0) [
                          rectangle,
                          draw,
                          double,
                          double distance=1mm
                        ] {Double};
%
\node (myNode2) at (0,-10mm) [
                          rectangle,
                          draw,
                          double=black!30,                          
                          double distance=1mm,
                          fill=green!30
                        ] {Double};
%
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \node [fill=black!30,fit=(myNode1) (myNode2)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you aren't happy with this, then you have to hack into the inner code as there is no relevant key involved. You may also define a new command.

Comment: This isn't an answer but too long for a comment.

Comment: Hello Harish. That's what I did as a workaround of course. I was hoping that there is a more general solution where the background can be "anything".

Comment: @ManuelKuehner More general solution needs some deep hack, I am afraid.

Comment: I accept the workaround since there is no real solution :(.

Answer (score 4):

Two more options where you don't need to worry about background color.

The first one (`doubleA` in code below) uses a `matrix` node. A `matrix` node is a `node` with some other `nodes` inside. Therefore, if `matrix` node is only drawn and not filled, it keeps its transparency. Be careful with this option because your internal node must finish with `\\`.

The second ont (`doubleB`) uses `append after command` option to draw a surrounding node with `fitting` library. Like with `doubleA` this outer node has no background if you dont `fill` it.

You can select `double line` separation adjusting `inner sep` for `matrix` or `fit` nodes. If you need to make further reference to this nodes you will need to select between outer or inner one. With `matrix`  solution you fix outer node name and inner one will be `name-1-1`, while with `fit` solution, you fix inner node name and outer one is called `name-b` (you can change this name).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,matrix}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{doubleA/.style = {matrix of nodes,
    draw, inner sep=1mm,
    nodes = {rectangle, draw, inner sep=.3333em}}}

\tikzset{doubleB/.style = {rectangle, draw, 
    append after command={
        \pgfextra{\node[fit=(\tikzlastnode), draw] (\tikzlastnode-b) {};}
    }}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[doubleA] at (0,0) (A) {Double\\};

\node[doubleB] at (0,-1)  (B) {Double};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \node [fill=black!30,fit={(A) (B-b)}] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update*

Another example which shows how to place or connect this kind of nodes. Every node is double, it's made with inner and outer nodes, therefore you can connect inner or outer nodes with any other one. You can also use inner or outer nodes to anchor them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{doubleA/.style = {matrix of nodes,
    draw, inner sep=1mm,
    nodes = {rectangle, draw, inner sep=.3333em}}}

\tikzset{doubleB/.style = {rectangle, draw, 
    append after command={
        \pgfextra{\node[fit=(\tikzlastnode), draw] (\tikzlastnode-b) {};}
    }}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[red!20] (-1,-1) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[help lines] (-1,-1) grid (4,4);

\node[doubleA] (A)  at (0,0) {DoubleA\\};

\node[doubleB, anchor=south west] at (2,1)  (B) {DoubleB};

\node[doubleA, matrix anchor=south west] at (1,3)  (C) {DoubleA\\};

\node[doubleA, matrix anchor=D-1-1.south west, above=2cm of A.center] (D) {DoubleA\\};

\draw [<->] (A) to [out=80, in=260] (D);
\draw [<->] (D-1-1.north) |-(C-1-1);
\draw [<->] (A-1-1) to [out=10, in=180] (B-b);
\draw [<->] (A) to [out=-10, in=-80] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx. In real I need this stuff to draw block diagrams (with right of...). I have to check if your idea still works when I connect the blocks and so on. Again - Thx.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner: I've added some examples showing how to place and connect this kind of nodes.

Comment: @Ignasi: This work around applies only to rectangles. Could you imagine another one that is applicable to all sort of (at least straight) lines - like double itself does?

Comment: @strpeter It applies to any "normal" kind of node. `matrix` and `fit` nodes can have any shape. I've tested with `ellipse` and `trapezium` and it works. What do you have in mind?

Comment: The command `\draw[doubleA] (A) -- (B);` draws a normal single line instead of a double one.

Comment: @strpeter    The question was about drawing a transparent border around a node. This is what `doubleA` does. It's not intended for drawing `double` lines. I've understood that you wanted to change node's shape, and this is also possible. Now I'm not sure about understanding your question.

Comment: @Ignasi: I should probably as a new question as it requires a different approach than you mentioned: C.f. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325388/25077