# Tikz double line core color transparency

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to remove the core color in double line in tikz ?

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle, background rectangle/.style={fill=lightgray}]

\draw[thin,double,-implies] (0,-0.8,0) -- (0,-1.9,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can't. A double line is drawn twice one with outer color and on top of it thinner line with the inner color.

Comment: Why don't you manually create a double arrow? Then you can adjust anything you like. You can put it in a macro and use it many times too.

Comment: There was a similar post before: [pgf/tikz: Making the filling / gap between double border lines transparent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159333/25077)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a refined solution, but if there is no alternative...

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle, background rectangle/.style={fill=lightgray}]

\draw[thin,double,-implies] (0,-0.8,0) -- (0,-1.9,0) ;
\draw[-Triangle Cap,lightgray,line width=.589pt] (0,-0.8,0) -- (0,-1.866,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not a simpler`\draw[thin,double=lightgray,-implies] (0,-0.8,0) -- (0,-1.9,0);`?

Comment: @Ignasi Because I didn't know you can add `=lightgray` after `double`?

Comment: `double` option can be used to fix the core color in double lines which is  `white` by default. (see section 15.3.4 in pgfmanual)

Comment: @Ignasi I think it could be useful if you add an answer...

Answer (score 2):

When background color is known and uniform, it's possible to simulate a transparent `double` line using the background color to fill the double line core.

`double` option draws a double line with a white core by default, but we can use `double=red` to select the inner color.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle, background rectangle/.style={fill=lightgray}]

\draw[thin,double,-implies] (0,-0.8) -- (0,-1.9);

\draw[thin,double=lightgray,-implies] (.5,-0.8) -- (.5,-1.9);

\draw[thin,double=red,-implies] (1,-0.8) -- (1,-1.9);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]