# Set background color for arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, arrows

I have a few arrows that I created for usage in math mode. I recently found out that the arrows seem to have a white background (between the two lines). This is a problem for me as I have a gray background in some parts of my document (e.g., definitions have a gray box as background).

I created these arrows mostly by copying stuff from the internet and modifying the arrows until they roughly looked the way I had in mind. However, I don't understand how I can modify the background color (the part between the lines). Is it somehow possible to have a transparent background (instead of white)?

Thank you for your help!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\xRightarrow}[1]{
    \mathrel{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= {( $ (current bounding box.south) + (0,-0.5ex) $ )}]
            \node[inner sep=.5ex] (a) {$\scriptstyle #1$};
            \path[draw,implies-,double distance between line centers=2pt] (a.south east) -- (a.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\newcommand{\xTwoheadrightarrow}[1]{
    \mathrel{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= {( $ (current bounding box.south) + (0,-0.5ex) $ )}]
            \node[inner sep=.5ex] (a) {$\scriptstyle #1$};
            \path[draw,implies-,double distance between line centers=2pt] (a.south east) -- (a.south west);
            \path[draw,implies-,double distance between line centers=2pt] ($ (a.south east) + (-0.079,0) $)--($ (a.south east) + (-0.08,0) $);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\newcommand{\xRightsquigarrow}[1]{
    \mathrel{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= {( $ (current bounding box.south) + (0,-0.5ex) $ )}]
            \node[inner sep=.5ex] (a) {$\scriptstyle #1$};
            \path[draw,implies-,double distance between line centers=1.5pt,decorate,decoration={zigzag,amplitude=0.7pt,segment length=1.2mm,pre=lineto,pre length=3pt}] (a.south east) -- (a.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{gray}

\noindent
$\xRightarrow{abcde}$ \\
$\xTwoheadrightarrow{abcde}$ \\
$\xRightsquigarrow{abcde}$ 

\end{document}
```

The corresponding output looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: You can not set the center color to transparent, but you will get the same result by setting it to the same color as your page `double=gray`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325388/tikz-double-line-core-color-transparency